# paper-menu-button's dropdown (paper-menu) not overlaying other iron-list items

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm running into an issue using polymer 1.0's `paper-menu-button`.  It's dropdown menu isn't overlaying neighbouring `iron-list` elements.

I am building an element that displays items using `iron-list`, and each item has a dropdown menu of options that can be performed on that particular `iron-list` item.  However, the `paper-menu-button`'s `paper-menu` dropdown is not appearing on top of neighbouring `iron-list` items, only on top of it's own list item.

I've tried inspecting items in Chrome, and playing around with z-index and overflow CSS settings to no avail.  Can anyone help me out with my overlay issue?

Here is an extract of my custom element's local DOM template (and see further below for screenshot):

**UPDATE:**  jsbin demonstrating the issue:

http://jsbin.com/kuyovuh/1/edit?html,output

**UPDATE #2:**  Also note that in Chrome 44 on mobile (Android), the paper-menu-button doesn't show dropdown at all in the above jsbin case.

```
<div id="projectsVertBoundary" class="layout vertical">

    <div id="projectsHorBoundary" class="layout horizontal center-center">

         <iron-list items="[[projects]]" indexAs="_id" as="projLI" class="layout flex">

             <template>

                    <div>
                        <paper-material id="itemShadow" animated elevation="1">

                            <div class="item layout horizontal" onmouseover="hoverOver(this)" onmouseout="hoverOut(this)">

                                <paper-menu-button id="projOptionsBtn" vertical-align="top" horizontal-align="right" class="layout fixed-right">
                                    <paper-icon-button id="projOptionsButtonIcon" icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
                                    <paper-menu id="projOptionsSelMenu" class="dropdown-content">
                                        <paper-icon-item id="projEdit"> 
                                            <iron-icon icon="create"></iron-icon> Edit Project
                                        </paper-icon-item>
                                        <paper-icon-item id="projCopy">
                                            <iron-icon icon="content-copy"></iron-icon> Copy Project
                                        </paper-icon-item>
                                        <paper-icon-item id="projDelete"> 
                                            <iron-icon icon="delete"></iron-icon> Delete Project
                                        </paper-icon-item>
                                    </paper-menu>
                                </paper-menu-button>

                                <div class="layout flex vertical">
                                    <!-- a bunch of arbitrary list item content -->
                                    Project Type:<p>[[projLI.kind]]</p>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                       </paper-material>
                  </div>

             </template>

        </iron-list>

   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you setup a working jsbin? I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @ebidel.  Added jsbin here:  http://jsbin.com/kuyovuh/1/edit?html,output    Also note that when you click on the last options menu item in the iron-list, no dropdown list appears at all.  Clicking on the options menu for Project One demonstrates the overlay issue.

Comment: Wonder if it's because things are in an iron-list, which applies transforms. Then you have the dropdown that is fixed position. I know Chrome does unexpected things when these two mix. Can you file a bug on paper-dropdown?

Comment: I have added a comment to an existing issue for paper-menu-button, with links to this SO thread and jsbin:  https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/issues/9

Comment: @ebidel, just wondering if you might be able to suggest a way to get the dropdown overlay working in the meantime? I'd like to continue using iron-list in this case, due to the potential for this array of items to become large and benefit from iron-list's handling of scrolling/paging etc.

Comment: Did you sort it out by any chance? Facing the same issue with an iron-list too....

Comment: did anyone found a solution for this issue??

Comment: My understanding is that the various overlay issues would be resolved with the polymer 2.0+ elements.  Haven't tried them yet to see if it has been fixed.  In my case, as it wasn't essential that I use iron-list, I retreated back to the use of a dom-repeat template, and all is well.