# Polymer paper-dropdown menu does not overlay iron-list

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, polymer-1.0, iron-list

My issue is similar to the one here: [paper-menu-button's dropdown (paper-menu) not overlaying other iron-list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884654/paper-menu-buttons-dropdown-paper-menu-not-overlaying-other-iron-list-items), but no adequate solution is proposed there.

The problem is that I have a `<paper-dropdown-menu>`, which opens up correctly inside the `<iron-list>` item it is in, but goes underneath the following `<iron-list>` items: [image: screenshot]

I have a simple `<paper-dropdown-menu>` like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu-light class="custom" label="Languages" no-label-float>
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
    <paper-item>Spanish</paper-item>
    <paper-item>English</paper-item>
    <paper-item>French</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Sinhala</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu-light>
```

which is inserted into another element with an `<iron-list>` (which loads a JSON file with `<iron-ajax>`):

```
<iron-list id="list" items="[[bookList.books]]" as="item">
  <template>
    <div>
      <div class$="[[getClassForItem(item, selected)]]" tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]" style="z-index: 1;">
        <div class="avatar">[[item.id]]</div>
        <div class="pad">
          <div class="primary">[[item.titleen]]</div>
          <div class="shortText">[[item.slug]]</div>
          <div class="longText">[[item.blurb]]</div>
            <div class="languagedrop">
              <language-drop></language-drop>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

I tried setting the z-index for each `<iron-list>` item to 1, but that did not work. I tried working with `<iron-overlay>`, but I did not manage to get that done. I'm very new to Polymer, so if anybody has a solution or workaround that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `iron-list` is using `transform: translate3d` for each list item.
The workaround that I have found is working is to add `z-index`to the current list item (`<div class="item"></div>`) on which you have the dropdown expanded, or to all items from top to bottom in descending order, programatically.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have an example code for me?

Comment: Looking... but I have just found that someone has removed that from our app and it stopped working as well, will update the answer ^^